# Chdir to ~/Library on Mac is returning an error, regardless of current directory

Tags: python, macos, python-os

My code:

```
import os
os.chdir("~/Library")
```

The error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled/tree_creation.py", line 13, in <module>
    os.chdir("~/Library")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Library'
```

I tried:

```
import os
os.chdir("/Users")
os.chdir("~/Library")
```

but that returned the same error.
The `~/Library` directory does exist(I think), since I was able to navigate to it with go to file.

What's going on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` is not automatically converted to a path. You can convert it using [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser).

```
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Library'))
```